# docker can't connect to another docker service

Tags: docker, sentry

I'm trying to run sentry onpremise version (https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise)

logs shows

```
relay_1                        | 2020-09-09T10:45:13Z [relay_server::actors::upstream] ERROR: authentication encountered error: could not send request to upstream
relay_1                        |   caused by: Failed to connect to host: Failed resolving hostname: no record found for name: web.router703710.com. type: AAAA class: IN
relay_1                        |   caused by: Failed resolving hostname: no record found for name: web.router703710.com. type: AAAA class: IN
relay_1                        |   caused by: Failed resolving hostname: no record found for name: web.router703710.com. type: AAAA class: IN
```

`router703710.com` is the dns assigned by our cisco router..
although we don't use it in any way.
I just see cisco has that dns setup in the router's setting page.

From the hostmachine where the docker is running, I can't connect to the `router703710.com` or `www.router703710.com` .

So how do I tell the docker not to use the dns and some other dns which is actually working?

Only thing I can think of are the following settings and not sure it'll make difference

```
 network_mode: host
  dns:
   -  192.168.1.1
```

The docker image seems to be https://hub.docker.com/r/getsentry/relay/ but I don't know how to see the actuall dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

It has been discussed in https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/issues/771 and it seems this issue is from Docker.  [agrevtcev](https://github.com/agrevtcev) has provided an workaround in that thread, to downgrade Docker to `19.03`.

I made some changes on the commands.  The latest Docker of `19.03` is `19.03.15` (not `19.03.14` in the original workaround), and use apt-mark to prevent from upgrading docker automatically (note this is for Ubuntu 20.04, focal):

```
apt install -y --allow-downgrades docker-ce=5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-focal docker-ce-cli=5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-focal
apt-mark hold docker-ce docker-ce-cli
```